# Diagonal part of Functional Derivative

Tags: calculus-of-variations, dirac-delta

Given an analytic function $f$, define
\begin{equation}
J[G]=\mathrm{Tr}\log\big(1-if(G)\big)
\end{equation}
with $G=G(x,y)$ a function of two (real) variables and the logarithm defined in a convolutional sense as
\begin{equation}
\log\big(1-if(G)\big)(x,y)=-if\big(G(x,y)\big)-\frac12\int\text{d}z\ if\big(G(x,z)\big)if\big(G(z,y)\big)+\dots\ .
\end{equation}
Is it true that
\begin{align}
\frac{\delta J[G]}{\delta G(x,y)}=&-if'\big(G(x,y)\big)\big[1-if(G)\big]^{-1}(y,x)\\\\
=&-if'\big(G(x,y)\big)\Big(\delta(x-y)+\int\text{d}z\ \big[1-if(G)\big]^{-1}(y,z)if(z,x)\Big)\ ?
\end{align}
I am having trouble evaluating the above expression for a function $f$ depending only on the diagonal elements of $G$, say
\begin{equation}
f\big(G(x,y)\big)=e^{G(x,x)}\ .
\end{equation}
It is then
\begin{equation}
f'\big(G(x,y)\big)=\delta(x-y)e^{G(x,x)}
\end{equation}
right? Such that
\begin{equation}
\frac{\delta J[G]}{\delta G(x,y)}=-i\delta(x-y)^2e^{G(x,x)}+\dots\ .
\end{equation}
In the end I would like to decompose the functional derivative of $J$ into a diagonal part $\sim\delta(x-y)$ and an off-diagonal part, is my calculation correct? I encounter the dreaded $\delta(x-y)^2$ which I am not sure how to work with here...
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After revisiting the problem I found that when
\begin{equation}
\frac{\delta f(x',y')}{\delta G(x,y)}=\frac12\big(\delta(x'-x)\delta(x'-y)+\delta(y'-x)\delta(y'-y)\big)A(x',y')+\delta(x'-x)\delta(y'-y)B(x',y')\ ,
\end{equation}
as is the case for example with
\begin{equation}
f(x,y)=\exp\big\{\frac12\big(G(x,x)+G(y,y)\big)\big\}\ ,
\end{equation}
the derivative evaluates to
\begin{equation}
\frac{\delta J[G]}{\delta G(x,y)}=-i\delta(x-y)\Big[\big(A*\big[1-if\big]^{-1}\big)(x,x)+B(x,x)\Big]+B(x,y)\big(\big[1-if\big]^{-1}*f\big)(y,x)\ .
\end{equation}